# How can I use script variable in <c:forEach> begin value

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, jstl, numberformatexception

This is my jsp source

```
<select id="preferAgeStart" name="preferAgeStart">
                        <c:forEach begin="20" end="35" step="1" var="age">
                            <option value=${age }>${age }</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
```

I want to append select tag id='preferAgeEnd' with using the value of 'preferAgeStart' as begin value of  c:forEach.
Here is my code.

```
$("#preferAgeStart").change(function(){
        var preferAgeStartStr = $(this).val();
        var preferAgeStart = parseInt(preferAgeStartStr);
        $('#preferAgeEnd').remove();
         $("#preferAgeStart").after(
            "<select id='preferAgeEnd' name='preferAgeEnd'>"
            + "<c:forEach begin='"
            + preferAgeStart
            + "' end='35' step='1' var='age'>"
            + "<option value=${age }>${age }</option>"
            + "</c:forEach>"
            + "</select>");
```

But it has NumberForamtException

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
            + preferAgeStart 
            + ""
```

how can i use `preferAgeStart` as an int value?

Comment: `<c:forEach>` isn't HTML and `Java != JavaScript`.

Comment: Do i have to change HTML to JSP? It's right?

Answer (score 0):

Think about when things are executed.
JSTL is executed on the server and the result is sent to the browser.
JQuery is executed by the browser.

So the SERVER is trying to execute the following before sending the page to the browser:

```
<c:forEach begin='"
+ preferAgeStart
+ "' end='35' step='1' var='age'>
```

The server doesn't know what preferAgeStart is because it isn't a variable until 
after the page has loaded and the user has changed the select value, so it errors.

For your code, you should execute a client-side loop, not a server-side loop.

ie.

```
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ 
//do something
}
```

Comment: When I didn't parse preferAgeStartStr, it occurs same error.